# Copy a line of text and paste into next available space in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to this world and have been asked to simplify some manual copy and paste that is done.

After reading a few posts I have found this code. This works perfectly to move the correct line into the different worksheet but I do not know how to change the code so that it pastes into a different workbook. If I put the name of the worksheet in it comes up with an error of subscript out of range.

any help would be appreciated, and sorry for what i am sure is a very basic question:

````
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

  Set copySheet = Worksheets("Score sheet")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  copySheet.Range("A37:Y37").Copy
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub```

.
````

Comment: You need to qualify the `Workbook` the worksheet is in as well.

Comment: Thank you, how do I do that? just write the workbook name and the sheet name all in the same line?

Comment: `Set copySheet = Workbooks("yourworkbookname").Worksheets("Score sheet")`... something like that.

Comment: thank you, added that but now get object variable or with block variable not set for this line of code: pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Did you `Set pasteSheet` as well?

Comment: got it working now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Score sheet").Range("A37:Y37").Copy
Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0). _
                        PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```